# VS Code, change NodeJS version for debugger

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I want to change NodeJS version from 4.5.0 to 7.7.2 for VS Code specifically for different projects.
I am using nvm on Mac, and I have two versions stated above. They are for different projects.

Even though I can change from terminal with nvm, VS Code uses default version. I need to change the default version every time and completely restart the VSCode.
Is there a way to alter configuration so it picks up the version I wanted
both for in-app terminal and for running project?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

After VS Code 1.21, there is a better solution than the original answer.

You can set `"runtimeVersion": "7.7.2"` and if you have nvm/nvs installed, it will be able to find that version of Node. Details: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_21#_node-debugging

--- Original answer ---

In your launch config, you can set a path to a Node executable from nvm like this: `"runtimeExecutable": "/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.1/bin/node"`

Comment: thanks very the answer, this can solve the problem. Please mark as the correct answer.

Comment: Thnx! Helped me a lot

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, how to find the launch config?

Comment: @fotoflo check this out -> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging