# Is it possible to point VS Code to a custom NodeJS installation directory?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

When I run my Node app via VS Code, it uses the node installed in my Program Files directory, but I specifically want to run it with a different version of Node, which is installed in my C:\NodeJS folder.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code, change NodeJS version for debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782144/vs-code-change-nodejs-version-for-debugger)

Answer (score 0):

This might also be helpful:

> **"nvm" support**
>
> If you are using "nvm" (or "nvm-windows") to manage your
>   Node.js versions it is now possible to specify a runtimeVersion
>   attribute in a launch configuration for selecting a specific version
>   of Node.js. Here is an example launch config:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch test",
  "runtimeVersion": "7.10.1",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test.js"
}
```

> Please note: Make sure to have those Node.js versions installed that
>   you want to use with the runtimeVersion attribute as the feature will
>   not download and install the version itself. So you will have to run
>   something like nvm install 7.10.1 from the integrated terminal if you
>   plan to add "runtimeVersion": "7.10.1" to your launch configuration.

From [node debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_node-debugging).  So you can set a node version in a launch config for purposes of debugging, but their doesn't appear to be a similar option for a task in tasks.json.